# How to add driver to an input of a node in the Animation Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, add-on, drivers, animation-nodes, graph-editor

Whenever i add a driver to an input of a node in animation nodes nothing appears in the Driver editor.

[image]

Comment: I see no way to see it in the graph editor. But nearly all the scene data is accessible to AN. So what should have been given by a driver should be calculated in AN instead.

Comment: But the thing is that i want the inputs driven by a custom panel

Comment: Use an expression node?

Comment: that's Too easy XD, also the driver method would save me pretty good time.

Answer (score 1):

I do realize this topic is a few years old, but this is one of the first results that shows up on Google when you search for this issue... so perhaps this can help some passersby:

A gentleman named Kuldeep Singh posted a workaround a while back, which would involve (for example) adding the driver instead to an empty's transform channel and then using an "Object > Transforms Input" node to feed that data into Animation Nodes. (Source: https://blender.community/c/graphicall/0hbbbc/)

His workaround may be purely academic for most situations, but perhaps there are niche applications where this might be practical. Hope this helps! Peace and God bless!